# CouchDB return One to First of Many

Tags: view, couchdb

I have a Couch database that contains tasks. These tasks can have multiple comments each. I would like a view that returns all tasks with only the single latest comment for each one.

Think of it like getting all blog posts along with only the most recent comment for each post.

Ie something like this possible?

Comment: Are the comments embedded in the tasks or stored as separate documents?

Comment: Stored as separate documents. Can a map/reduce be used to do this somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh the options you have! What works best will be largely dependent on your use case.

### Separate with Client Filtering

In this approach, the client gets all the information and makes the decision about what to show. You can start by showing the most recent comment, and if the users wants to view more it'll be instant -- no more requests because you've already received the data!

Example comment:

```js
{
    "_id": "89f34369f0a50685bcb0682103003b2d",
    "_rev": "1-f64ffb6e374b8055b2fcdaa040f26a4f",
    "taskId": "89f34369f0a50685bcb0682103002037",
    "text": "use the tire pressure in the driver's side door jamb",
    "type": "comment",
    "timestamp": 300
}
```

Example task:

```js
{
    "_id": "89f34369f0a50685bcb0682103002037",
    "_rev": "1-6249079866249429dc35ba113d4772de",
    "type": "task",
    "text": "check tire pressure"
}
```

View to give you tasks and comments:

```js
{
    "_id": "_design/mydesign",
    "_rev": "1-3ac9fa693c8b20f9598a4c667009ed45",
    "views": {
        "tasks_with_most_recent_comment": {
            "map": "function(doc) { if(doc.type === 'task') { emit([doc._id, 0], doc); } else if (doc.type === 'comment') { emit([doc.taskId, 1], doc); } }"
        }
    }
}
```

In the result, all of your tasks will have `key[1] === 0` while all comments have `key[1] === 1`.

### Separate and Most Recent Embedded

If I had a read-heavy application that received lots of comments, I'd consider modeling comments as a separate document and embed the most recent comment in the task.

- PRO: every task now has all the information you need to display
- CON: client now needs to ensure that every comment is persisted as a comment and updates the task

Example comment:

```js
{
    "_id": "89f34369f0a50685bcb0682103003b2d",
    "_rev": "1-f64ffb6e374b8055b2fcdaa040f26a4f",
    "taskId": "89f34369f0a50685bcb0682103002037",
    "text": "use the tire pressure in the driver's side door jamb",
    "type": "comment",
    "timestamp": 300
}
```

Example task:

```js
{
    "_id": "89f34369f0a50685bcb0682103002037",
    "_rev": "1-6249079866249429dc35ba113d4772de",
    "type": "task",
    "text": "check tire pressure",
    "mostRecentComment": {
        "_id": "89f34369f0a50685bcb0682103003b2d",
        "_rev": "1-f64ffb6e374b8055b2fcdaa040f26a4f",
        "taskId": "89f34369f0a50685bcb0682103002037",
        "text": "use the tire pressure in the driver's side door jamb",
        "type": "comment",
        "timestamp": 300
    }
}
```

In this approach, getting the most recent comment is handled on write, so the query to retrieve it is very straightforward.

### Every Comment Embedded

If comments are infrequent, maybe it makes sense to embed all of them in a task like this:

```js
{
    "_id": "89f34369f0a50685bcb0682103000640",
    "_rev": "1-5fb40b1d24bdbacbbb652112dfb3e3e5",
    "text": "pick up milk",
    "comments": [
        { "timestamp": 100000000, "text": "first"  },
        { "timestamp": 900000000, "text": "last"   },
        { "timestamp": 800000000, "text": "middle" }
    ]
}
```

A reasonable way of pulling only the most recent would be to sort `doc.comments` in descending order by timestamp, then grab the first one.

We can't do that literally because [views cannot update documents](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/couchapp/views/intro.html#wrapping-up); they must be side-effect free. So while it's tempting to simply call `doc.comments.sort` with a comparator, that will attempt to [sort in place](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), mutate the comments array, and throw an error:

```
Log :: function raised exception (new TypeError("doc.comments.sort(function (a, b) {return b.timestamp - a.timestamp;}) is read-only", "undefined", 1)) with doc._id 89f34369f0a50685bcb0682103000640
```

Instead, we can call upon [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to give us a shallow copy of the array.

```js
var recentComments = doc.comments.slice()    // new array we're free to modify
    .sort(function(a, b) {                   // sort in place
        return b.timestamp - a.timestamp;    // descending order by timestamp
    }).slice(0,1);                           // take only the first result as an array
```

So now we have a comments array of just the latest comment. We already know we can't reassign it, so let's build another object to give to our `emit` function. Note the new object should contain all the fields you care about.

```js
emit(doc._id, {text: doc.text, comments: recentComments});
```

All this gives us a final view of:

```js
{
    "_id": "_design/mydesign",
    "_rev": "1-be95f2e2a699bb7182184dbc0729d3ce",
    "views": {
        "task_with_most_recent_comment": {
            "map": "function(doc){ emit(doc._id, {text: doc.text, comments: doc.comments.slice().sort(function(a, b) { return b.timestamp - a.timestamp; }).slice(0,1) }); }}"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess the first solution you mentioned is the best, although I won't be having the client do the filtering, but instead NodeJS. The problem is I'm currently returning all tasks and comments, but it's getting quite large and takes a while to load into the browser. So using node to trim down to only the latest comments should do the trick.

Comment: I was just hoping there would be some magic I could run right within CouchDB to make it happen.